# Spring MVC handle request error 400 , custom message or object with @ResponseStatus

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is there a way to handle server codes returned by Spring framework.

The below method is only allowed to handle content-type=> application/json. So, if If the request body is empty, then it throws error 400 with description **"The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect."**

The control does not within the code, if the request body is empty. I am trying to print a custom message for error code 400, but it is not working. What I might be missing , it there way to return custom object?

```
     @RequestMapping(value = "/allUsers", method = RequestMethod.GET ,produces={"application/json"})
@ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST , reason="Content not allowed")
        public @ResponseBody HashMap<String, String> home(Locale locale, Model model) {
            logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

            HashMap<String, String> users=new HashMap<String, String>();
            users.put("name", "John");
            users.put("location", "UK");

            return users;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding throws Exception in your method inside controller.